# changing UISegmented controllers font

Tags: swift, uisegmentedcontrol

does anyone know how to change the font of a custom UISegmented controller. In code as IB doesn't do all the other things I want to do with the controller!

the code I have is:

```
let items = ["Classic", "Cool Blue", "Safari", "Motors", "Old School"]
let customSC = UISegmentedControl(items: items)
customSC.selectedSegmentIndex = 3
customSC.frame = CGRectMake(ScreenWidth/2 - (ScreenWidth*0.342), ScreenHeight/2, (ScreenWidth*0.684), (ScreenHeight*0.085))
customSC.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
customSC.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
customSC.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
customSC.font // font doesn't exist.... 

// add the SC target action
customSC.addTarget(self, action: "changeScheme:", forControlEvents:.ValueChanged)
self.view.addSubview(customSC)
```

thanks in advance to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the method you are looking for is:

```
func setTitleTextAttributes(_ attributes: [NSObject : AnyObject]?, forState state: UIControlState)
```

Something like:

```
let attrs = [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "AmericanTypewriter", size: 10.0)!]
customSC.setTitleTextAttributes(attrs, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Comment: thanks a lot Freedom. I have been trying versions of that one, but it just makes the segmented controller disappear altogether. :-(

Comment: thanks Freedom. For some reason the animations I had on the segmented controller were hiding it. Now it works great. Much appreciated.